# How does Cloud-Torrenting Works

Tags: cloud, torrent

I am having a question reguarding cloud torrent,where we paste magnet links and the file is ready for download. 
How do these sites make the torrent available so fast even without many seeds?

Some examples are [Offcloud](https://offcloud.com/?=41525785) , [Seedr](https://www.seedr.cc)

Answer (score 0):

if large files are available instantly, it's likely that these servers are actually a seed and that the file is available to download locally on their own network.